# Switch between FileGDB and OpenFileGDB

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I am using ArcGIS GDBs in QGIS (3.26.2 installed via OSGeoaW on Windows 10). As I want to edit features, I recently installed FileGDB in addition to OpenFileGDB which can only read the GDBs. Now opening existing QGIS projects containing GDBs takes very long (I know that FileGDB is slower).

Is it therefore possible to swich between the two drivers before startup or to enable/disable FileGDB from within QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

"Is it therefore possible to swich between the two drivers before startup?"

Not sure. Probably yes.

"Or enable/disable FileGDB from within QGIS?"

1. Go to `Settings`
2. `Options...`
3. `Data Sources`
4. `GDAL`
5. `Vector Drivers`
6. Toggle desired drivers
   [image]

"Or is there any other reason why opening existing projects now takes so long?"

1. Open the `Debugging/Development Tools`
2. Choose the `profiler` (little clock)
   [image]

Comment: This did the trick! It is a bit cumbersome to start QGIS, select the drivers and restart, but it saves minutes of loading. Thanks a lot!